# Blank screen displays After running ng new and ng serve with Angular CLI

Tags: angular

I try to run Angular web project. And I have installed npm and node.js with nvm and I am using visual studio code as an editor. After following the steps. I get the blank screen as a result. kindly hope someone could help me with the issue.

Steps followed

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new PROJECT
cd PROJECT
ng serve
```

After performing the above steps server is up. but when Navigate to http://localhost:4200/ . it shows blankpage.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'pre-interview';
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
 enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>PreInterview</title>
 <base href="/">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * The content below * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * is only a placeholder * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * and can be replaced. * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * Delete the template below * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * to get started with your project! * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->

<style>
 :host {
   font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #333;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 }

 h1,
 h2,
 h3,
 h4,
 h5,
 h6 {
   margin: 8px 0;
 }

 p {
   margin: 0;
 }

 .spacer {
   flex: 1;
 }

 .toolbar {
   height: 60px;
   margin: -8px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #1976d2;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
 }

 .toolbar img {
   margin: 0 16px;
 }

 .toolbar #twitter-logo {
   height: 40px;
   margin: 0 16px;
 }

 .toolbar #twitter-logo:hover {
   opacity: 0.8;
 }

 .content {
   display: flex;
   margin: 32px auto;
   padding: 0 16px;
   max-width: 960px;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
 }

 svg.material-icons {
   height: 24px;
   width: auto;
 }

 svg.material-icons:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 8px;
 }

 .card svg.material-icons path {
   fill: #888;
 }

 .card-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-top: 16px;
 }

 .card {
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   height: 40px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0 8px 16px;
   padding: 16px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   line-height: 24px;
 }

 .card-container .card:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 0;
 }

 .card.card-small {
   height: 16px;
   width: 168px;
 }

 .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card) {
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover {
   transform: translateY(-3px);
   box-shadow: 0 4px 17px rgba(black, 0.35);
 }

 .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover .material-icons path {
   fill: rgb(105, 103, 103);
 }

 .card.highlight-card {
   background-color: #1976d2;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
   border: none;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 30%;
   position: relative;
 }

 .card.card.highlight-card span {
   margin-left: 60px;
 }

 svg#rocket {
   width: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: -10px;
   top: -24px;
 }

 svg#rocket-smoke {
   height: 100vh;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   right: 180px;
   z-index: -10;
 }

 a,
 a:visited,
 a:hover {
   color: #1976d2;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 a:hover {
   color: #125699;
 }

 .terminal {
   position: relative;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 600px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding-top: 45px;
   margin-top: 8px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: rgb(15, 15, 16);
 }

 .terminal::before {
   content: "\2022 \2022 \2022";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 4px;
   background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
   color: #c2c3c4;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 2rem;
   line-height: 0;
   padding: 14px 0;
   text-indent: 4px;
 }

 .terminal pre {
   font-family: SFMono-Regular,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,monospace;
   color: white;
   padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
   margin: 0;
 }

 .circle-link {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   border-radius: 40px;
   margin: 8px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
   transition: 1s ease-out;
 }

 .circle-link:hover {
   transform: translateY(-0.25rem);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }

 footer {
   margin-top: 8px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   line-height: 20px;
 }

 footer a {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }

 .github-star-badge {
   color: #24292e;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(27,31,35,.2);
   border-radius: 3px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#fafbfc,#eff3f6 90%);
   margin-left: 4px;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol;
 }

 .github-star-badge:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#f0f3f6,#e6ebf1 90%);
   border-color: rgba(27,31,35,.35);
   background-position: -.5em;
 }

 .github-star-badge .material-icons {
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   margin-right: 4px;
 }

 svg#clouds {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: -160px;
   left: -230px;
   z-index: -10;
   width: 1920px;
 }


 /* Responsive Styles */
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

   .card-container > *:not(.circle-link) ,
   .terminal {
     width: 100%;
   }

   .card:not(.highlight-card) {
     height: 16px;
     margin: 8px 0;
   }

   .card.highlight-card span {
     margin-left: 72px;
   }

   svg#rocket-smoke {
     right: 120px;
     transform: rotate(-5deg);
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
   svg#rocket-smoke {
     display: none;
     visibility: hidden;
   }
 }
</style>

<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
 <img
   width="40"
   alt="Angular Logo"
   src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg=="
 />
 <span>Welcome</span>
   <div class="spacer"></div>
 <a aria-label="Angular on twitter" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://twitter.com/angular" title="Twitter">

   <svg id="twitter-logo" height="24" data-name="Logo — FIXED" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
     <defs>
       <style>
         .cls-1 {
           fill: none;
         }

         .cls-2 {
           fill: #ffffff;
         }
       </style>
     </defs>
     <rect class="cls-1" width="400" height="400" />
     <path class="cls-2" d="M153.62,301.59c94.34,0,145.94-78.16,145.94-145.94,0-2.22,0-4.43-.15-6.63A104.36,104.36,0,0,0,325,122.47a102.38,102.38,0,0,1-29.46,8.07,51.47,51.47,0,0,0,22.55-28.37,102.79,102.79,0,0,1-32.57,12.45,51.34,51.34,0,0,0-87.41,46.78A145.62,145.62,0,0,1,92.4,107.81a51.33,51.33,0,0,0,15.88,68.47A50.91,50.91,0,0,1,85,169.86c0,.21,0,.43,0,.65a51.31,51.31,0,0,0,41.15,50.28,51.21,51.21,0,0,1-23.16.88,51.35,51.35,0,0,0,47.92,35.62,102.92,102.92,0,0,1-63.7,22A104.41,104.41,0,0,1,75,278.55a145.21,145.21,0,0,0,78.62,23"
     />
   </svg>

 </a>
</div>

<div class="content" role="main">

 <!-- Highlight Card -->
 <div class="card highlight-card card-small">

   <svg id="rocket" alt="Rocket Ship" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="101.678" height="101.678" viewBox="0 0 101.678 101.678">
     <g id="Group_83" data-name="Group 83" transform="translate(-141 -696)">
       <circle id="Ellipse_8" data-name="Ellipse 8" cx="50.839" cy="50.839" r="50.839" transform="translate(141 696)" fill="#dd0031"/>
       <g id="Group_47" data-name="Group 47" transform="translate(165.185 720.185)">
         <path id="Path_33" data-name="Path 33" d="M3.4,42.615a3.084,3.084,0,0,0,3.553,3.553,21.419,21.419,0,0,0,12.215-6.107L9.511,30.4A21.419,21.419,0,0,0,3.4,42.615Z" transform="translate(0.371 3.363)" fill="#fff"/>
         <path id="Path_34" data-name="Path 34" d="M53.3,3.221A3.09,3.09,0,0,0,50.081,0,48.227,48.227,0,0,0,18.322,13.437c-6-1.666-14.991-1.221-18.322,7.218A33.892,33.892,0,0,1,9.439,25.1l-.333.666a3.013,3.013,0,0,0,.555,3.553L23.985,43.641a2.9,2.9,0,0,0,3.553.555l.666-.333A33.892,33.892,0,0,1,32.647,53.3c8.55-3.664,8.884-12.326,7.218-18.322A48.227,48.227,0,0,0,53.3,3.221ZM34.424,9.772a6.439,6.439,0,1,1,9.106,9.106,6.368,6.368,0,0,1-9.106,0A6.467,6.467,0,0,1,34.424,9.772Z" transform="translate(0 0.005)" fill="#fff"/>
       </g>
     </g>
   </svg>

   <span>{{ title }} app is running!</span>

   <svg id="rocket-smoke" alt="Rocket Ship Smoke" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="516.119" height="1083.632" viewBox="0 0 516.119 1083.632">
     <path id="Path_40" data-name="Path 40" d="M644.6,141S143.02,215.537,147.049,870.207s342.774,201.755,342.774,201.755S404.659,847.213,388.815,762.2c-27.116-145.51-11.551-384.124,271.9-609.1C671.15,139.365,644.6,141,644.6,141Z" transform="translate(-147.025 -140.939)" fill="#f5f5f5"/>
   </svg>

 </div>

 <!-- Resources -->
 <h2>Resources</h2>
 <p>Here are some links to help you get started:</p>

 <div class="card-container">
   <a class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 13.18v4L12 21l7-3.82v-4L12 17l-7-3.82zM12 3L1 9l11 6 9-4.91V17h2V9L12 3z"/></svg>

     <span>Learn Angular</span>

     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></svg>    </a>

   <a class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9.4 16.6L4.8 12l4.6-4.6L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.4-1.4zm5.2 0l4.6-4.6-4.6-4.6L16 6l6 6-6 6-1.4-1.4z"/></svg>

     <span>CLI Documentation</span>

     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></svg>
   </a>

   <a class="card" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M13.5.67s.74 2.65.74 4.8c0 2.06-1.35 3.73-3.41 3.73-2.07 0-3.63-1.67-3.63-3.73l.03-.36C5.21 7.51 4 10.62 4 14c0 4.42 3.58 8 8 8s8-3.58 8-8C20 8.61 17.41 3.8 13.5.67zM11.71 19c-1.78 0-3.22-1.4-3.22-3.14 0-1.62 1.05-2.76 2.81-3.12 1.77-.36 3.6-1.21 4.62-2.58.39 1.29.59 2.65.59 4.04 0 2.65-2.15 4.8-4.8 4.8z"/></svg>

     <span>Angular Blog</span>

     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/></svg>
   </a>

 </div>

 <!-- Next Steps -->
 <h2>Next Steps</h2>
 <p>What do you want to do next with your app?</p>

 <input type="hidden" #selection>

 <div class="card-container">
   <div class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'component'" tabindex="0">
       <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>

     <span>New Component</span>
   </div>

   <div class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'material'" tabindex="0">
       <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>

     <span>Angular Material</span>
   </div>

   <div class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'dependency'" tabindex="0">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>

     <span>Add Dependency</span>
   </div>

   <div class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'test'" tabindex="0">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>

     <span>Run and Watch Tests</span>
   </div>

   <div class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'build'" tabindex="0">
     <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>

     <span>Build for Production</span>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Terminal -->
 <div class="terminal" [ngSwitch]="selection.value">
     <pre *ngSwitchDefault>ng generate component xyz</pre>
     <pre *ngSwitchCase="'material'">ng add @angular/material</pre>
     <pre *ngSwitchCase="'dependency'">ng add _____</pre>
     <pre *ngSwitchCase="'test'">ng test</pre>
     <pre *ngSwitchCase="'build'">ng build --prod</pre>
 </div>

 <!-- Links -->
 <div class="card-container">
   <a class="circle-link" title="Animations" href="https://angular.io/guide/animations" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg id="Group_20" data-name="Group 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21.813" height="23.453" viewBox="0 0 21.813 23.453">
       <path id="Path_15" data-name="Path 15" d="M4099.584,972.736h0l-10.882,3.9,1.637,14.4,9.245,5.153,9.245-5.153,1.686-14.4Z" transform="translate(-4088.702 -972.736)" fill="#ffa726"/>
       <path id="Path_16" data-name="Path 16" d="M4181.516,972.736v23.453l9.245-5.153,1.686-14.4Z" transform="translate(-4170.633 -972.736)" fill="#fb8c00"/>
       <path id="Path_17" data-name="Path 17" d="M4137.529,1076.127l-7.7-3.723,4.417-2.721,7.753,3.723Z" transform="translate(-4125.003 -1058.315)" fill="#ffe0b2"/>
       <path id="Path_18" data-name="Path 18" d="M4137.529,1051.705l-7.7-3.723,4.417-2.721,7.753,3.723Z" transform="translate(-4125.003 -1036.757)" fill="#fff3e0"/>
       <path id="Path_19" data-name="Path 19" d="M4137.529,1027.283l-7.7-3.723,4.417-2.721,7.753,3.723Z" transform="translate(-4125.003 -1015.199)" fill="#fff"/>
     </svg>
   </a>

   <a class="circle-link" title="CLI" href="https://cli.angular.io/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg alt="Angular CLI Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21.762" height="23.447" viewBox="0 0 21.762 23.447">
       <g id="Group_21" data-name="Group 21" transform="translate(0)">
         <path id="Path_20" data-name="Path 20" d="M2660.313,313.618h0l-10.833,3.9,1.637,14.4,9.2,5.152,9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-2649.48 -313.618)" fill="#37474f"/>
         <path id="Path_21" data-name="Path 21" d="M2741.883,313.618v23.447l9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-2731.05 -313.618)" fill="#263238"/>
         <path id="Path_22" data-name="Path 22" d="M2692.293,379.169h11.724V368.618h-11.724Zm11.159-.6h-10.608v-9.345h10.621v9.345Z" transform="translate(-2687.274 -362.17)" fill="#fff"/>
         <path id="Path_23" data-name="Path 23" d="M2709.331,393.688l.4.416,2.265-2.28-2.294-2.294-.4.4,1.893,1.893Z" transform="translate(-2702.289 -380.631)" fill="#fff"/>
         <rect id="Rectangle_12" data-name="Rectangle 12" width="3.517" height="0.469" transform="translate(9.709 13.744)" fill="#fff"/>
       </g>
     </svg>
   </a>

   <a class="circle-link" title="Augury" href="https://augury.rangle.io/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg alt="Angular Augury Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="21.81" height="23.447" viewBox="0 0 21.81 23.447">
       <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip-path">
           <rect id="Rectangle_13" data-name="Rectangle 13" width="10.338" height="10.27" fill="none"/>
         </clipPath>
       </defs>
       <g id="Group_25" data-name="Group 25" transform="translate(0)">
         <path id="Path_24" data-name="Path 24" d="M3780.155,311.417h0l-10.881,3.9,1.637,14.4,9.244,5.152,9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-3769.274 -311.417)" fill="#4a3493"/>
         <path id="Path_25" data-name="Path 25" d="M3862.088,311.417v23.447l9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-3851.207 -311.417)" fill="#311b92"/>
         <g id="Group_24" data-name="Group 24" transform="translate(6.194 6.73)" opacity="0.5">
           <g id="Group_23" data-name="Group 23" transform="translate(0 0)">
             <g id="Group_22" data-name="Group 22" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
               <path id="Path_26" data-name="Path 26" d="M3832.4,373.252a5.168,5.168,0,1,1-5.828-4.383,5.216,5.216,0,0,1,2.574.3,3.017,3.017,0,1,0,3.252,4.086Z" transform="translate(-3822.107 -368.821)" fill="#fff"/>
             </g>
           </g>
         </g>
         <path id="Path_27" data-name="Path 27" d="M3830.582,370.848a5.162,5.162,0,1,1-3.254-4.086,3.017,3.017,0,1,0,3.252,4.086Z" transform="translate(-3814.311 -359.969)" fill="#fff"/>
       </g>
     </svg>
   </a>

   <a class="circle-link" title="Protractor" href="https://www.protractortest.org/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg alt="Angular Protractor Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21.81" height="23.447" viewBox="0 0 21.81 23.447">
       <g id="Group_26" data-name="Group 26" transform="translate(0)">
         <path id="Path_28" data-name="Path 28" d="M4620.155,311.417h0l-10.881,3.9,1.637,14.4,9.244,5.152,9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-4609.274 -311.417)" fill="#e13439"/>
         <path id="Path_29" data-name="Path 29" d="M4702.088,311.417v23.447l9.244-5.152,1.685-14.4Z" transform="translate(-4691.207 -311.417)" fill="#b52f32"/>
         <path id="Path_30" data-name="Path 30" d="M4651.044,369.58v-.421h1.483a7.6,7.6,0,0,0-2.106-5.052l-1.123,1.123-.3-.3,1.122-1.121a7.588,7.588,0,0,0-4.946-2.055v1.482h-.421v-1.485a7.589,7.589,0,0,0-5.051,2.058l1.122,1.121-.3.3-1.123-1.123a7.591,7.591,0,0,0-2.106,5.052h1.482v.421h-1.489v1.734h15.241V369.58Zm-10.966-.263a4.835,4.835,0,0,1,9.67,0Z" transform="translate(-4634.008 -355.852)" fill="#fff"/>
       </g>
     </svg>
   </a>

   <a class="circle-link" title="Find a Local Meetup" href="https://www.meetup.com/find/?keywords=angular" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg alt="Meetup Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.607" height="23.447" viewBox="0 0 24.607 23.447">
       <path id="logo--mSwarm" d="M21.221,14.95A4.393,4.393,0,0,1,17.6,19.281a4.452,4.452,0,0,1-.8.069c-.09,0-.125.035-.154.117a2.939,2.939,0,0,1-2.506,2.091,2.868,2.868,0,0,1-2.248-.624.168.168,0,0,0-.245-.005,3.926,3.926,0,0,1-2.589.741,4.015,4.015,0,0,1-3.7-3.347,2.7,2.7,0,0,1-.043-.38c0-.106-.042-.146-.143-.166a3.524,3.524,0,0,1-1.516-.69A3.623,3.623,0,0,1,2.23,14.557a3.66,3.66,0,0,1,1.077-3.085.138.138,0,0,0,.026-.2,3.348,3.348,0,0,1-.451-1.821,3.46,3.46,0,0,1,2.749-3.28.44.44,0,0,0,.355-.281,5.072,5.072,0,0,1,3.863-3,5.028,5.028,0,0,1,3.555.666.31.31,0,0,0,.271.03A4.5,4.5,0,0,1,18.3,4.7a4.4,4.4,0,0,1,1.334,2.751,3.658,3.658,0,0,1,.022.706.131.131,0,0,0,.1.157,2.432,2.432,0,0,1,1.574,1.645,2.464,2.464,0,0,1-.7,2.616c-.065.064-.051.1-.014.166A4.321,4.321,0,0,1,21.221,14.95ZM13.4,14.607a2.09,2.09,0,0,0,1.409,1.982,4.7,4.7,0,0,0,1.275.221,1.807,1.807,0,0,0,.9-.151.542.542,0,0,0,.321-.545.558.558,0,0,0-.359-.534,1.2,1.2,0,0,0-.254-.078c-.262-.047-.526-.086-.787-.138a.674.674,0,0,1-.617-.75,3.394,3.394,0,0,1,.218-1.109c.217-.658.509-1.286.79-1.918a15.609,15.609,0,0,0,.745-1.86,1.95,1.95,0,0,0,.06-1.073,1.286,1.286,0,0,0-1.051-1.033,1.977,1.977,0,0,0-1.521.2.339.339,0,0,1-.446-.042c-.1-.092-.2-.189-.307-.284a1.214,1.214,0,0,0-1.643-.061,7.563,7.563,0,0,1-.614.512A.588.588,0,0,1,10.883,8c-.215-.115-.437-.215-.659-.316a2.153,2.153,0,0,0-.695-.248A2.091,2.091,0,0,0,7.541,8.562a9.915,9.915,0,0,0-.405.986c-.559,1.545-1.015,3.123-1.487,4.7a1.528,1.528,0,0,0,.634,1.777,1.755,1.755,0,0,0,1.5.211,1.35,1.35,0,0,0,.824-.858c.543-1.281,1.032-2.584,1.55-3.875.142-.355.28-.712.432-1.064a.548.548,0,0,1,.851-.24.622.622,0,0,1,.185.539,2.161,2.161,0,0,1-.181.621c-.337.852-.68,1.7-1.018,2.552a2.564,2.564,0,0,0-.173.528.624.624,0,0,0,.333.71,1.073,1.073,0,0,0,.814.034,1.22,1.22,0,0,0,.657-.655q.758-1.488,1.511-2.978.35-.687.709-1.37a1.073,1.073,0,0,1,.357-.434.43.43,0,0,1,.463-.016.373.373,0,0,1,.153.387.7.7,0,0,1-.057.236c-.065.157-.127.316-.2.469-.42.883-.846,1.763-1.262,2.648A2.463,2.463,0,0,0,13.4,14.607Zm5.888,6.508a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-2.179.006,1.09,1.09,0,0,0,2.179-.006ZM1.028,12.139a1.038,1.038,0,1,0,.01-2.075,1.038,1.038,0,0,0-.01,2.075ZM13.782.528a1.027,1.027,0,1,0-.011,2.055A1.027,1.027,0,0,0,13.782.528ZM22.21,6.95a.882.882,0,0,0-1.763.011A.882.882,0,0,0,22.21,6.95ZM4.153,4.439a.785.785,0,1,0,.787-.78A.766.766,0,0,0,4.153,4.439Zm8.221,18.22a.676.676,0,1,0-.677.666A.671.671,0,0,0,12.374,22.658ZM22.872,12.2a.674.674,0,0,0-.665.665.656.656,0,0,0,.655.643.634.634,0,0,0,.655-.644A.654.654,0,0,0,22.872,12.2ZM7.171-.123A.546.546,0,0,0,6.613.43a.553.553,0,1,0,1.106,0A.539.539,0,0,0,7.171-.123ZM24.119,9.234a.507.507,0,0,0-.493.488.494.494,0,0,0,.494.494.48.48,0,0,0,.487-.483A.491.491,0,0,0,24.119,9.234Zm-19.454,9.7a.5.5,0,0,0-.488-.488.491.491,0,0,0-.487.5.483.483,0,0,0,.491.479A.49.49,0,0,0,4.665,18.936Z" transform="translate(0 0.123)" fill="#f64060"/>
     </svg>
   </a>

   <a class="circle-link" title="Join the Conversation on Gitter" href="https://gitter.im/angular/angular" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
     <svg alt="Gitter Logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19.447" height="19.447" viewBox="0 0 19.447 19.447">
       <g id="Group_40" data-name="Group 40" transform="translate(-1612 -405)">
         <rect id="Rectangle_19" data-name="Rectangle 19" width="19.447" height="19.447" transform="translate(1612 405)" fill="#e60257"/>
         <g id="gitter" transform="translate(1617.795 408.636)">
           <g id="Group_33" data-name="Group 33" transform="translate(0 0)">
             <rect id="Rectangle_15" data-name="Rectangle 15" width="1.04" height="9.601" transform="translate(2.304 2.324)" fill="#fff"/>
             <rect id="Rectangle_16" data-name="Rectangle 16" width="1.04" height="9.601" transform="translate(4.607 2.324)" fill="#fff"/>
             <rect id="Rectangle_17" data-name="Rectangle 17" width="1.04" height="4.648" transform="translate(6.91 2.324)" fill="#fff"/>
             <rect id="Rectangle_18" data-name="Rectangle 18" width="1.04" height="6.971" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="#fff"/>
           </g>
         </g>
       </g>
     </svg>
   </a>
 </div>

 <!-- Footer -->
 <footer>
     Love Angular?&nbsp;
     <a href="https://github.com/angular/angular" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> Give our repo a star.
       <div class="github-star-badge">
           <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"/></svg>
         Star
       </div>
     </a>
     <a href="https://github.com/angular/angular" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
       <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" fill="#1976d2"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
     </a>
 </footer>

 <svg id="clouds" alt="Gray Clouds Background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2611.084" height="485.677" viewBox="0 0 2611.084 485.677">
   <path id="Path_39" data-name="Path 39" d="M2379.709,863.793c10-93-77-171-168-149-52-114-225-105-264,15-75,3-140,59-152,133-30,2.83-66.725,9.829-93.5,26.25-26.771-16.421-63.5-23.42-93.5-26.25-12-74-77-130-152-133-39-120-212-129-264-15-54.084-13.075-106.753,9.173-138.488,48.9-31.734-39.726-84.4-61.974-138.487-48.9-52-114-225-105-264,15a162.027,162.027,0,0,0-103.147,43.044c-30.633-45.365-87.1-72.091-145.206-58.044-52-114-225-105-264,15-75,3-140,59-152,133-53,5-127,23-130,83-2,42,35,72,70,86,49,20,106,18,157,5a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c47,94,178,113,251,33,61.112,8.015,113.854-5.72,150.492-29.764a165.62,165.62,0,0,0,110.861-3.236c47,94,178,113,251,33,31.385,4.116,60.563,2.495,86.487-3.311,25.924,5.806,55.1,7.427,86.488,3.311,73,80,204,61,251-33a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c51,13,108,15,157-5a147.188,147.188,0,0,0,33.5-18.694,147.217,147.217,0,0,0,33.5,18.694c49,20,106,18,157,5a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c47,94,178,113,251,33C2446.709,1093.793,2554.709,922.793,2379.709,863.793Z" transform="translate(142.69 -634.312)" fill="#eee"/>
 </svg>

</div>

<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * The content above * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * is only a placeholder * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * and can be replaced. * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * End of Placeholder * * * * * * * * * * * -->
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->



<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

when Navigate to http://localhost:4200/ in Chrome, I got nothing on the console.There is no error.I have uninstalled the cli and reinstalled it but nothing changes.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Update : 
I did ng build to generate a dist package and config a Vhost Apache for it and it works !!  So I think somehow the problem is related to the web pack server or angular cli......But I always don't know why with the ng serve and http://localhost:4200 it doesn't work......

Comment: Is the result the same in different browsers as well?

Comment: Please remove the code from `<style> .... </style>` and put it in the app.component.css file, also if you can pase the  AppRoutingModule file

Comment: @John Yes the result is the same in different browers.

Comment: @XuchenZHANG see answer please

Comment: Can you try running chrome with the –disable-extensions option? app-root is empty which means angular isn't even being loaded. With all those tools in the upper right, its possible one of them is blocking your app. Also check the network tab. Do all the dependencies get downloaded?

Comment: @shadowfox476 Thanks for answering. I have tried what you said, but still nothing. and in the network tab, there is only localhost with status 200

Comment: I am curious about the `Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/` ... can you please run `npm install` in console and ng serve again

Comment: Still the same, but when I tried` npm install` I got : `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}) .............`

Comment: Please copy and paste the result of: node -v and ng --version when you type it in command line -- it might be the best to update angular-cli and node to the latest.

Comment: node -v
 v12.12.0          

ng --version 
Angular CLI: 8.3.9
Node: 12.12.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.11

Comment: Update : I did ng build to generate a dist package and config a Vhost Apache for it and it works !! So I think somehow the problem is related to the web pack server or angular cli......But I always don't know why with the ng serve and http://localhost:4200 it doesn't work......

Answer (score 1):

> open tsconfig.json file

make sure these lines are same, as mentioned blow

```
"declaration": true,
"noEmitHelpers": false,
```

> optional

```
"isolatedModules": false
```

> retry the `ng build` than `ng serve` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, blank page is a sign that it works but it's stuck in the `index.html` page, and is not redirecting you to the `app.component.html` page. You have to investigate what's causing it to be stuck there.

I had similar problem, but it seems yours is a bit different. Mine was because in the `app.component.ts` file, then in the `@Component` decorator, the `selector` wasn't assigned to the tag that has the same name as the one in my `index.html` tag inside the body, usually the name of that tag would be `app-root`.

That's the tag that `index.html` uses to display contents from `app.component.html`, so it's important for them to have the same name. But I see yours already has this, but I'm just writing this down just in case someone did the same mistake as me.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. The selector was set to `inventory-app-root`, When I changed it to `app-root`, the page started loading up with images.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzwses)

I moved the style content to app.component.css file.

I commented `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` since you have some issue probably in that code.

if you do this it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I did the same thing as in your code, but it still doesn't work, always the same problem.

Comment: What do you see in the Network section of chrome debugger ?

Comment: Only localhost with status 200

Answer (score 0):

I came back to edit a project that I usually work on and I was presented with a blank page (Totally empty html) and network tab showed the request with status:400!!!

I tested on another browser and it worked just fine. SO my solution was to clear all data for `localhost` from FireFox. Seems to be a cookie issue for me. Hope this helps for anyone landed here.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself upgrading from Angular8 to Angular 9+, this error occurs due to the fact that localization with i18 was introduced.

To fix this run the following command in your terminal from your root directory:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```